# Find the last $2$ digits of $3^{2024}$ using binomial expansion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem

> Find the last two digits of
> $$3^{2024}$$

I can easily do this question (see below) but is there a way of doing it by binomial expansion?
I tried to expand the expression to a few terms but in vain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

By seeing some comments, I am compelled to ask if this question can really be solved using binomial$?$

**EDIT**
My solution without binomial expansion:
$$3^{15}\equiv 7\pmod{100}\implies$$
$$3^{2010}\equiv 7^{134}\equiv7^2 \pmod{100}\implies$$
$$3^{2024}\equiv 7^2\cdot3^{14}\equiv 7\cdot3^9\equiv 3^4 \pmod{100}$$
Hence the answer is $3^4$ i.e. $81$

Comment: Binomial expansion $(a+b)^{2024}$ for which $a,b$? And how did you use the Chinese remainder therorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Per preferred_anon's comment.)*

Note that

$$3^{2024} = 9^{1012} $$
$$= (10-1)^{1012} = 10^{1012} - {1012\choose 1}10^{1011}+\cdots+{1012\choose 1010}10^2 -{1012\choose 1011}10 +1 $$

$\equiv -10120+1 \equiv -20 +1 \equiv 81 \pmod{100}.$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).